# How to fill in the missing date in data setB and then blend Data setA and B by Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I have 2 data sources and both are from the same one object. It was separated because some technical reason.

data set A looks like

```
 { 
 [Date: 2018/1/1,2018/1/2,2018/1/3],
 [Cost: 100.0,200.0,300.0]
 }
```

data set B

```
{
[Date: 2018/1/1,2018/1/3],
[(Category: SOAP, 
  Qty: 20),
 (Category: SHAMPOO,
  Qty: 5)
[(Category: SOAP,
 Qty: 2),
 (Category: SHAMPOO,
  Qty: 10)
 ]
}
```

data set B has missing the row 2018/1/2. I want to fill in the missing date in data set B and then put null in SOAP and SHAMPOO. finally, to blend Data set A and B into one charts.

So, Does anyone know how to fill in the missing date(2018/1/2) in data set B?

Answer (score 0):

Take both the data sources in tableau and then blend those but while blending take care that data set A should be at the left of the blend and data set B should be at right of the blend, because blend is always a `left Join`

After blend when you see the result set you should be able to see the missing date with null values

Comment: I found [a way to fix the issue](https://community.tableau.com/thread/223378) but a new issue got. the new issue is that I can't using continuous to drawing charts. I will try yours. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

With blending there's always a risk with this problem; what about if a record only exists in B? In SQL you'd want to do a FULL OUTER JOIN ideally

If you have to use blended data, the best approach would be to get a dates datasource and then blend both A and B on that. This is the safest method and will mean that if B doesn't exist in A or vice versa, it'll always be included

Comment: I found [a way to fix the issue](https://community.tableau.com/thread/223378) but a new issue got. the new issue is that I can't using continuous to drawing charts. I will try yours. Thanks :)